# mysql - get max result by group of results

Tags: mysql

Im totally stuck with a query.
I have a query that looks like this:

```
select dr_machine, 
  dr_worker, 
  min(dr_date) as firstDate, 
  max(dr_date) as lastDate 
from data 
where dr_machine IS NOT NULL 
  && dr_worker IS NOT NULL 
group by dr_worker, dr_machine 
order by dr_machine;
```

The result will be this:

```
+------------+-------------------+------------+------------+
| dr_machine | dr_worker         | firstDate  | lastDate   |
+------------+-------------------+------------+------------+
| KBA R-     | john              | 1242165600 | 1423350000 |
| KBA R-     | peter             | 1305237600 | 1316642400 |
| KBA R-     | philip            | 1248040800 | 1423522800 |
| Solna      | marie             | 1298453600 | 1378453600 |
| Solna      | laura             | 1278453600 | 1398453600 |
| Solna      | anne              | 1288453600 | 1388453600 |
+------------+-------------------+------------+------------+
```

I want it to display the min and max dr_date from the dr_machine, not the dr_worker (as it is now)
So that the result looks like this:

```
+------------+-------------------+------------+------------+
| dr_machine | dr_worker         | firstDate  | lastDate   |
+------------+-------------------+------------+------------+
| KBA R-     | john              | 1242165600 | 1423522800 |
| KBA R-     | peter             | 1242165600 | 1423522800 |
| KBA R-     | philip            | 1242165600 | 1423522800 |
| Solna      | marie             | 1278453600 | 1398453600 |
| Solna      | laura             | 1278453600 | 1398453600 |
| Solna      | anne              | 1278453600 | 1398453600 |
+------------+-------------------+------------+------------+
```

Earlier I combined this result with another query in php that looks like this:

```
select dr_machine, 
  min(dr_date) as firstDate, 
  max(dr_date) as lastDate 
from data 
where dr_date IS NOT NULL 
group by dr_machine;
```

I've tried different join and subqueries, but honestly I've no idea what I was doing and the result never became what I wanted it to be.

Best regards
Niclas

Comment: Please post the whole content of the `data` table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not 100% understood your issue, but my guess is:

```
select data.dr_machine, 
  data.dr_worker, 
  t.firstDate, 
  t.lastDate 
from data 
left join(
select dr_machine, 
  min(dr_date) as firstDate, 
  max(dr_date) as lastDate 
from data 
group by dr_machine ) as t
on data.dr_machine = t.dr_machine
where data.dr_machine IS NOT NULL 
  && data.dr_worker IS NOT NULL 
order by data.dr_machine,data.dr_worker
```

Comment: Thanks! I added group by dr_machine, dr_worker and the result became what I wanted it to be (select data.dr_machine,    data.dr_worker,    t.firstDate,    t.lastDate  from data  left join( select dr_machine,    min(dr_date) as firstDate,    max(dr_date) as lastDate  from data  group by dr_machine ) as t on data.dr_machine = t.dr_machine where data.dr_machine IS NOT NULL    && data.dr_worker IS NOT NULL  group by dr_machine, dr_worker order by data.dr_machine,data.dr_worker;)

Answer (score 0):

I would start by writing a query that gets just that information for the dr_machine, like you already have:

```
SELECT dr_machine, MIN(dr_date) AS firstDate, MAX(dr_date) AS lastDate
FROm data
WHERE dr_date IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY dr_machine;
```

Then, just join that subquery with your table to get the dr_worker column:

```
SELECT d.dr_machine, d.dr_worker, tmp.firstDate, tmp.lastDate
FROM data d
JOIN(
   SELECT dr_machine, MIN(dr_date) AS firstDate, MAX(dr_date) AS lastDate
   FROM data
   WHERE dr_date IS NOT NULL
   GROUP BY dr_machine) tmp ON tmp.dr_machine = d.dr_machine AND dr_worker IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY d.dr_machine, d.dr_worker;
```